# Configure GitHub Pages failed

Tags: github-actions, github-pages

I was trying to use GitHub Pages (Static HTML By GitHub Actions) and facing this error.

Run actions/configure-pages@v2.1.1 
Warning: Get Pages site failed 
Error: Create Pages site failed 
Error: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403

Any idea how to resolve it? All I have in my repository is a simple index.html which says

## Hello

Any leads would be helpful, Thank you.

[**Configure GitHub pages failed**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4zlZ.png)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I think I found a solution.

I created a website project using next.js and I wanted some students I'm teaching to fork the project and be able to have their own sites too.
The build worked on my site, but kept failing on the forked sites.

So we went into Settings/Pages in the forked projects and set the Source to GitHub Actions.

[image: Screenshot of setting]

I had done this on the original project and used a template to make the workflow file, but it seems you need to do this again when forking the project (or adding the workflow file manually).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, curious why this was not mentioned anywhere in GitHub's docs.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue while configuring GitHub actions for next.js app.[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6zXh.png)

Instead of using safari browser, switching to chrome browser resolved my issue.